# Why does Magento limit Newsletter sending to 20?

Tags: newsletter, smtp, schedule, magento-cron

I am currently midst sending a newsletter to 12782 subscribers, it has been going since 3:00am this morning and now it is 22:41, but has only sent 4740 emails.

Investigating further it has come to my attention that the rate has been limited to 20 here:

```
 public function scheduledSend($schedule)
{
    $countOfQueue  = 3;
    $countOfSubscritions = 20;

    /** @var Mage_Newsletter_Model_Resource_Queue_Collection $collection */
    $collection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/queue')->getCollection()
        ->setPageSize($countOfQueue)
        ->setCurPage(1)
        ->addOnlyForSendingFilter()
        ->load();

     $collection->walk('sendPerSubscriber', array($countOfSubscritions));
}
```

In app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Model\Observer.php

I have tried searching online but cannot find why there is such a limit.

Moreover, not sure if it has a contributing factor but my cron and smtp pro settings are as such:

[image: Cron Settings]

[image: Smtp pro settings]

Answer (score 0):

Because those are just default settings for basic setup.

If you want to send much more than that without being pegged as spam and blacklisted, then you'll want to be sure spf records at a minimum are in place.

Mxtoolbox.com, or comodo.com is a good place to start.

Comment: Mxtoolbox is a great tool I use frequently, I don't want to push it too quick. Just wondering a) why smtp pro didn't pick up the 20 limit, would have been good to be able to change with the pauses config and such. B) or why it is hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

About why there is a limit: Because you shouldn't send 12k mails from your web server at once.
One of the reasons is, that an excessive mail traffic is one of the best indicators for a spamming system/server (many more factors are considered though).
In general it is a better practice to outsource huge mail campaigns to tools and servers that are actually made for this - a common web server usually isn't - or at least relay via one (in that case you may as well consider increasing the send rate to a value confirmed with your server admin).

About why it is 3/20: I not able to answer why it would be set to exactly to that - however, when considering that a server is usually not only sending newsletters and furthermore usually not only sending mails for one vhost, it makes sense to keep the limit low to reduce the risk of getting the server's IP blacklisted.

Comment: Thank you, but I am aware of this and am planning mail chimp use in future. Just wanted to at least give magento a chance and test capabilities.

Comment: @VaishalPatel Been there, tried it, wouldn't recommend it - but that might just be my personal opinion ;) But since we're there already, for me it is lacking of basic features such as proper test mails. Apart from that it is difficult for an end-user to set up nicely looking mailings due to the editor in general. Though, for a merchant who does know HTML and CSS - and what to take care about when sending HTML mails - it is certainly an option.

Comment: I have heard positive things. Few free tools out there to test for free.

Comment: About the free tools you're certainly right - especially when it comes to a bigger number of subscriptions like in your case. Yet, maintaining a good reputation of your own SMTP can also be quite a headache.

Comment: For now lets see how magento goes.